# Magento 2. Looking at Magento 2 provided API they all start with /V1/... why?

Tags: magento2, api

[image]Looking at Magento 2 provided API they all start with /V1/...

Why is this? Is it mandatory? What is the reason behind this?

Thanks

Comment: I guess its just a convention, to specify the API version number.  Yes its mandatory. Because thats whats set in the endpoint declaration.

Comment: Let's say I make a custom API endpoint why should I follow this convention? what are the perks?

Comment: This is a good question. I am always saying it is a Version Number, but where are the other versions ? But I think the Magento 2 API is the Version 2 of Magento 1 API despite it is written V1. Also I did a search and this what I found https://inviqa.com/blog/magento-2-tutorial-overview-web-api

Comment: @Jsparo30 the version of Magento's 2 API has nothing to do with Magento 1.

Comment: @vitoriodachef this kind of versioning convention is not only used by magento. There are many API's out there which also use this convention. You don't have to follow the convention but why wouldn't you?

Comment: @AndréFerraz I like to know why I'm doing things. It's just how my mind works.